# How to recover reputation and badges from when I was an unregistered user stackoverflow.com

Tags: support, user-accounts

I posted some questions on Stack Overflow, I got some badges and reputation. I cleaned cookies in browser and now I am not able to continue asking under that unregistered user. Is there a way for me to recover that reputation, badges, and history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new account and ask someone of the team (here or using mail) to merge your registered and unregistered account (and file a note in your registered account that you want that one to be merged with the unregistered one, to prevent account terrorism).

Answer (score 1):

Email team@stackoverflow.com with the link to the profile of the unregistered account as well as your current account.

To find the profile of the unregistered account, find a question or answer made with that account, then click on the Gravatar or the username. That will take you to the profile page.